# dwt2 matlab function results not the same in python pywt.dwt2 funtion

Tags: python, matlab, image-processing, wavelet-transform

Iam working on an brain tumor classification project, it's originally made in matlab and I am trying to implement it in python, I am facing problems with reimplementing the 2D wavelet transform part in python.

This is the implementation in matlab:-

```
img = imread('1Perfect.jpg');
img = imresize(img,[200,200]);
thr = im2bw(img);
signal1 = thr(:,:);

[cA1,cH1,cV1,cD1] = dwt2(signal1,'db4');
[cA2,cH2,cV2,cD2] = dwt2(cA1,'db4');
[cA3,cH3,cV3,cD3] = dwt2(cA2,'db4');
DWT_feat = [cA3,cH3,cV3,cD3];

imshow(imresize(DWT_feat,[110,450]));
```

this results the this:-

[image]

Now this is my python implementation:-

```
img = cv2.imread("1Perfect.jpg")
img = cv2.resize(img, dsize=(200, 200), interpolation=cv2.INTER_CUBIC)
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
(thresh, result) = cv2.threshold(gray, 127.5, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

cA1, (cH1, cV1, cD1) = pywt.dwt2(result[:, :], 'db4')
cA2, (cH2, cV2, cD2) = pywt.dwt2(cA1, 'db4')
cA3, (cH3, cV3, cD3) = pywt.dwt2(cA2, 'db4')
DWT_feat = np.concatenate((cA3, cH3, cV3, cD3), axis=1)

cv2.imshow("frame", cv2.resize(feats, dsize=(450, 110), interpolation=cv2.INTER_CUBIC))
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

this is the result:-

[image]

So what iam missing here?

Comment: Why would you apply a wavelet transform to a binary image? Why binarize first?

Comment: You should start simpler: compare the binarized images, then compare the results of the first wavelet transform, and make sure it is not a difference caused by the display.

Comment: This is what the original matlab implementation do, I am trying t understand it, here's the original implementation link https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/55107-brain-mri-tumor-detection-and-classification?s_tid=mwa_osa_a